# When does $g_n \circ f_n \rightarrow^{p} g \circ f$ imply $f_n \rightarrow^{p} f$?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $g_n \circ f_n \rightarrow^{p} g \circ f $ where $\rightarrow^{p}$ refers to convergence in probability (i.e. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P\{|g_n ( f_n(x)) - g(f(x))| > \varepsilon\} = 0$ for any $\varepsilon >0$), I am wondering what conditions are required to conclude that $f_n \rightarrow^{p} f$ (this is somewhat like a reverse continuous mapping theorem).

My guess is that a strengthening to uniform convergence $\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}} |g_n \circ f - g \circ f| = o_p(1)$ is required, but I am not too confident.

Edit: I am particularly interested in the case where $g(f(x)) = x$ (i.e. $g \circ f$ is the identity function) and $x$ is a random variable which need not be bounded but presumably $E|x|^p < \infty$ for some $p > 0$.

Edit2: $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Take $g_n=0$, $f_n=1$ and $f=3$. Then $g_n\circ f_n\to_p g\circ f$ but $f_n\not\to_p f$.

Comment: Thanks, I do need the assumption that neither $g$ nor $f$ are constant on their support.

Comment: OK. Take $g_n = \begin{cases} 0 & x \ne 15 \\ 73 & x = 15 \end{cases}$; now it's non constant. You can do much the same for $f$, by defining $f_n(x) = 3$ except when $x = \frac1n$, and $f_n(\frac1n) = 3 + \frac1n$. So "non constant" isn't nearly enough.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. I will have to add that both $g$ and $f$ are continuous. ( For context, both $f$ and $g$ will be estimated by neural networks sieve estimators and thus a continuity assumption will be imposed to appeal to the universal approximation theorem. And you might see that $g \circ f$ is actually an autoencoder.)